# Expected Ruby Version >= 1.8.7, is 1.8.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, rubygems

The Rails application that I am working on has a memory leak. I tried installing the Bleak_house gem to pinpoint the error, but got the following error:

```
sudo gem install bleak_house

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:48: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
Expected Ruby Version >= 1.8.7, is 1.8.5
```

The Ruby version in use is `1.8.7` and the Rubygems version used is `1.8.25`. I have even installed RVM and executed `rvm --default use 1.8.7` successfully, but it did not solve the issue. What could be the problem?

Comment: I recommend you open an issue on the github repo, as this question is very localized to that product. https://github.com/evan/bleak_house/issues

Comment: When you run sudo,it usually scrubs environment variables so the command you are running has probably forgotten all about rvm and is probably picking up some old system installed ruby. Use rvmsudo to get a sudo that preserves rvm

Comment: When you are typing `ruby -v` in console, what it is showing to you ?

Comment: When I type ruby -v, this is the output:
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371)

I tried using rvmsudo. This time, it attempted to download bleak_house (finally!!), but then it hit an error:

ERROR:  Error installing bleak_house:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Tried installing memprof. Hit the version error. Tried using rvmsudo. This time, I could install it successfully. Still no luck with bleak_house gem though :(

Comment: I will try to install it. Wait.

Comment: @user2153253, it doesn't want to install in my computer too, but errors are other.

Comment: Oh that's bad. Any alternatives to bleak_house that would help you find the code lines causing memory leak? I cannot use any option that publishes code online, or those which require you to submit them your code.
Thanks a lot for your help.